# SQL database backup in VB.NET not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
Dim str As String = "BACKUP DATABASE abc TO DISK='" & Application.StartupPath & "\abc.bak" & "'"
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(str, Conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Conn.Close()
```

can any one help me?

what's the problem in this vb code ... I am unable to get the result

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: the backup is not coming i.e abc.bak is not generated. and even there is no any errors

Comment: Does that SQL Server instance run on your own local machine? Otherwise, the backup will be generated **on  that machine** where the SQL Server instance is running ....

Answer (score 1):

The SQL backup runs on the SQL server. Therefore, `abc.bak` is generated on the SQL server itself, not on the PC running the application code above, so your use of `Application.StartupPath` doesn't make much sense - unless you're also running the code on the server?

If you're not, it should be possible to generate the backup using a UNC path. However, you'll need to make sure the account the SQL service is running as has sufficient permissions to write the file.

Comment: But when I run same query in SSMS it will give the result.

Comment: If you remove `Application.StartupPath` and check the SQL default directory, is the `.bak` file in there?

Comment: I think its better to write a stored procedure for this....

Comment: No there is no any out put in default directory i.e DATA or even in Backup.